# Understanding where/when I need to use onAuthStateChanged() - Firebase / Next.js

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, next.js

This is the index.js page to a project built from the [with-firebase-authentication](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-authentication) example (Next.js)

```
const Index = () => {
  const { user, logout } = useUser();

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <>
        <p>TEST</p>
        <p>
          You are not signed in.{" "}
          <Link href={"/auth"}>
            <a>Sign in</a>
          </Link>
        </p>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <AddClient></AddClient>
      <ToolBar />
      <Clients />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Index;
```

The Clients component is meant to list a bunch of firestore documents. This is how the component is written:

```
const Clients = () => {
    const { user, logout } = useUser();
    const [clients, setClients] = useState([]);
    var userRef = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
    useEffect(() => {
    firebase.firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(userRef.uid)
      .collection('clients')
      .onSnapshot(snap => {
        const clients = snap.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data()
        }));
        setClients(clients);
      });
  }, []);
  
    return (
        <div>
        <ul>
          {clients.map(client =>
            <li key={client.id}>
              {client.name}
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Clients;
```

If, in index.js the return is conditional to there being a user object  - how can Client which is within this return, see 'user' as undefined.

I tried using onAuthStateChanged() and tried using firebase.auth().currentUser in place of a user reference and user.uid - I keep getting a mixture of these errors:

> Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined

> User is not defined

> Clients(...) returned empty

I figure the answer to my question is "make sure you wait for firebase auth before trying to access user.uid" - but I can't seem to make that happen in Clients.

**UPDATE**
When trying to use onAuthStateChanged to verify a user exists before trying to interact with its uid - I came across an error “Rendered more hooks than during the previous render”.

Seperately...

I actually managed to get the (somewhat) desired effect by removing useEffect and writing it like this:

```
const Clients = () => {


    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {

          const db = firebase.firestore();
          db.collection('users')
          .doc(user.uid)
          .collection('clients')
          .onSnapshot(snap => {
              const clients = snap.docs.map(doc => ({
                  id: doc.id,
                  ...doc.data()
              }));
              setClients(clients);
          });
        } else {
         []
        }
      });

    const [clients, setClients] = useState([]);
   
    return (
        <div>
        <ul>
          {clients.map(client =>
            <li key={client.id}>
              {client.name}
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  };
  
  export default Clients;
```

However, this clearly isn't 'right' as when I log out - i get about 30,000 error messages in console saying:

> react_devtools_backend.js:2273 Uncaught Error in snapshot listener:
> FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

But when i'm logged in as any user - I get the properly rendered list without console errors.

Comment: is the users/clients collection changing constantly? or why are you using onSnapshot?

Comment: Yes the list of clients will be changing regularly (not necessarily constantly) - Clients will also eventually have a 'records' collection of docs that will update even more frequently. I'm using onSnapshot after following this: https://medium.com/swlh/lets-create-blog-app-with-next-js-react-hooks-and-firebase-backend-tutorial-7ce6fd7bbb3a#2e94